# How to write 2 values in one line and read them later again? Python

Tags: python, file

I want to create a Programm that saves login information in a file. So I think the best way is to write the username and password like this:

```
username # password
```

But how to writhe it so and how to read it again? My Code writes in 3 lines instead of one:

```
file = open(“testfile.txt”,”w”) 

file.write(username) 
file.write(“#”) 
file.write(password) 

file.close() 

file = open(“testfile.txt”, “r”)
print file.read(1)
```

How can I make the programm only write in one line?

**Edit** I need to save to 2 Values in the variables again.

Comment: Use `json` to dump structured data to a file and read it back. But please reconsider saving sensitive information in a text file ? But for educational purpose, sure, why not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will let you write both usernames and passwords in one line:

```
username, password = 'username', 'password'

with open("testfile.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write(f"{username} # {password}")
```

To read from your file

```
lines = [] 
with open('testfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        lines.append(line)
print(lines[0]) # this will print line 1
```

Comment: But how can I save the values in variables again?

Comment: @JonasX you after you read the file? if so, let me know if you have a single user pass or a list of users and passwords

Comment: I want to read one line each time I read it. So the first time read line 1 and the 2. time read line 2

Comment: @JonasX is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

For reading you can use the split function:

```
print(file.readline().split('#'))
```

Comment: that would print the username?

Comment: hm i now tried your code but i got an error: expected an indented block 'file' why?